# hamcrest matching on actual empty list fails with nosuchmethoderror

Tags: hamcrest

Sometimes the actual asserted upon can be surprisingly different.
A list can be empty while it was expected to contain something... what a surprise...

```java
assertThat(new ArrayList<Integer>(), equalTo(singletonList(7)));
```

```java
assertThat(new ArrayList<>(), not(Matchers.empty()));
```

both result in `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(java.lang.Object, org.hamcrest.Description)'`

(hamcrest 2.1 on jdk 14)

Answer (score 0):

Added a dependency having transitive dependency on Hamcrest 1.1 -- excluded and now it works as expected.